# Can one move back up a text file in VB6?

Tags: vb6, file

I have a program that is reading a text file, and owing to the vagaries of the file definition and the definitions of the objects the data has to be shovelled in to, I appear to have a need to move the read pointer of the file back up the file for a line, in a manner roughly analagous to the FORTRAN `BACKSPACE` statement.

Is there any method of doing this, either with native VB6 statements or with VB6 FileSystem objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure VB6 provides a seek() function to do this.

Otherwise, if the file is relatively small you could read it all into memory and use the split() function to separate it into lines. These could then be accessed however you want. Obviously if the file is large this is not a good idea though.

The FSO only lets you read forwards.

Comment: Yes, the `Seek` function takes a file number and a byte position: `Seek #1, 100` The documentation seems to be impossible to find online, but here's an [article about it](http://www.vbi.org/Items/article.asp?id=17).

Comment: Ah yes, Seek. Good call. Of course that would also mean having to know the length of the line/data as opposed to reading a whole line at a time by default.

Comment: You actually want the Seek *statement*, there is a Seek *function* but it simply returns the current byte position. Cody has the syntax correct `Seek #1, 100` moves to byte number 100 (there is no byte zero). Here's the online documentation ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266268(v=VS.60).aspx  For this problem I would actually suggest another approach, just write a wrapper object that saves the last line in a private variable, and exposes a "rewind one line" method.

Comment: @MarkJ: Hmm, statements look suspiciously like functions. I had no idea there was a difference here. I suppose my feet have been firmly planted in the .NET world a bit too long. Not to mention I did very little file I/O in my VB 6 days.

Comment: @Cody VB6 IO is littered with specialised statements. It would be far preferable the language designers had used functions instead. But I think those language decisions were made long ago, in QuickBasic, GWBasic and beyond. The VB.Net language designers decided to break backwards compatibility, which is very nice for new code but [causes pain if you own VB6 code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this in VB6. What you could do is to either read the whole file, a line at a time, into an array and then iterate through the array as needed. Or if that caused memory issues, then create a data structure and use Input to read a line into an instance of the structure based upon the line number.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion, which is probably what I should have done in the first place.